# Cannot resolve import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I need to create a recyclerview in Android Studio. I don't know why it keeps saying that it cannot resolve symbol recyclerview. I have done all the step according to those website tutorial.

My app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.1.1'
    //card view
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.1.1'
    //recyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.1.1'
    //picasso library to retrive images
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
```

May I know what's wrong with my code in the gradle file? Thanks in advance.
Here is my error report in logcat:

[image: error]

Comment: Post your logcat instead of a screenshot

Comment: You have half jetpack and half appcompat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to access the wrong package.

try androidx.recyclerview instead of the legacy android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

you should replace all the com.android.support.* dependencies, and replace with the androidx equivalent. (currently, you have a mix of both androidx and the legacy android.support dependencies)

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview

you can try using the Refactor> Migrate to AndroidX option on Android Studio for the auto fix

[image]

Answer (score 2):

replace you recyclerview library with this -> androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
as you are using the androidx, but your recycler view's library is still in support library format

to get proper migration information do refer to this -> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate